# Configuring Multisite with subdomains

Tags: multisite, multi-language, subdomains

I'm currently trying to configure multisite for my blog. I want to use it for multilingual content.

My installation of wordpress is located in a subfolder:

mydomain.de/content

everything worked fine so far. I installed it using all the guides out there and am now able to configure new sites. I added a site called "en.mydomain.de".

My question is, how am i supposed to set up the subdomain now, to get wordpress to recognize that i want to land on the other site? Like where do i need to point the address "en.mydomain.de" to?

I already tried pointing it to the root and to the /content folder. Is there anyone who knows how exactly wordpress manages to defer sites using the subdomain used? If so it could help me infer what the problem might be with my sites.

Comment: When setting up a MultiSite install, you need to configure it to be for either sub-directories, or sub-domains. Which way is your's set up?

Comment: It is set up for subdomains because one of the guides said, that its not possible to use subfolders if wordpress is not installed in the root of the webspace. That's where i'm stuck because i dont know how to connect subdomains with the wordpress sites.

Comment: I run a subdirectory type install, and I use a domain mapping plugin to setup all my subdomains. But I'm not sure how it would work in your case. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/